# Does swinject re instantiate the object?

Tags: ios, swift, swinject

I have a question, I'm using Swinject in a separate framework.

My app get the object from this framework and my appExtension use it too.

But in the Extension the Object is not correctly instantiate. Does Swinject use the first instance of my object or just recreate another one ?

thanks

Comment: I think it recreate another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found this in their documentation:

> **Graph (the default scope)**
>
> With ObjectScope.graph, an instance is always created, as in
>   ObjectScope.transient, if you directly call resolve method of a
>   container, but instances resolved in factory closures are shared
>   during the resolution of the root instance to construct the object
>   graph.

So, If you haven't specified the scope, that's the one that's applying in your case.

Complete documentation: https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/ObjectScopes.md